# Dask dataframe containing json format column

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dask dataframe containing a column in json format, and I want to parse the column into dataframe format.

the column in json format looks like:

`{"Name": {"id": 1000, "address": "ABC", ....}},,,`

So I want to extract only value of "Name", and make each keys in them a column, each values a values in it, like:

```
id    address ...
1000  ABC
2000  DEF
3000  GHA
...   ...
```

I think we can read json file into dask dataframe by read_json, but how could I do that?

Comment: How would you do this with Pandas ?

Comment: If it's pandas dataframe, I would do  use json_normalize from pandas.io.json, like (not working in dask dataframe),
df_json = json_normalize(df['json_col'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)))
df_json.head()

Comment: So you could do something similar with dask bag, `db.read_text('datajsonl').map(json.loads).compute()
` .  Then convert to a dataframe with `.to_dataframe`.  Have you read over https://examples.dask.org/applications/json-data-on-the-web.html  ?

Comment: @quasiben , please submit this as an answer, so it doesn't look like the question is pending

Comment: @quasiben sorry, there's 1 thing I did not mention. I read data from mysql using read_sql_table method. so, I can't use other methods to read like read_text. I mean, the output dataframe by read_sql_table contains a column in json format, which I want to normalize.

Answer (score -1):

The operation that you're doing appears to be embarrasingly parallel.  As a result, you can write a Pandas function and then apply that function across a dask dataframe in parallel.

```
def f(df: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    ... however you would do this in Pandas

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(f)
```

Comment: This won't work without the `meta` keyword. Please provide complete answers or avoid commenting at all!